# Why are all the elements in this array, programmed in python, contain the same string?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Can anyone help me with my problem please? Why are all the elements in this array contain the same string? The below piece of code prints the following result:
When you enter one string it will print this:

['bbb']

When you enter a different string it will print this:

['SSS', 'SSS']

When you enter another different string it will print this:

['nnn', 'nnn', 'nnn']

& so on. It keeps overwriting the previous string element & replacing it with the new one. Here's my code below:

```
global currentpage

currentpage += 1
for row in rows:
    #print(row)

    STORING_info = []
    dataINdatabase = ''.join(row)
    while len(STORING_info) < currentpage:
        STORING_info.append(dataINdatabase)
    print(STORING_info)
```

In theory it suppose to be more like this:

['bbb', 'SSS', 'nnn']

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe move

```
STORING_info = []
```

out of the loop. Also check

```
while len(STORING_info) < currentpage:
    STORING_info.append(dataINdatabase)
```

which just repeats the first element for the length of currentpage.

You need to explain what you want to do with currentpage,
without it, the list fills as expected.

```
global currentpage

currentpage += 1
STORING_info = []
for row in rows:
    dataINdatabase = ''.join(row)
    STORING_info.append(dataINdatabase)

print(STORING_info)
```